# Way to make the Date the parent value?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Hi I was wondering if there was a way to make the date the parent value? at the moment a random value is being generated.

```
  $(function(){

// CREATE A REFERENCE TO FIREBASE
 var dateRef = new Firebase('https://shiftsapp.firebaseio.com/roster');

 // REGISTER DOM ELEMENTS
 var date1Field = $('#date1Input');
 var emp1put1Field = $('#emp1Input1');
 var emp2put1Field = $('#emp2Input1');
 var emp3put1Field = $('#emp3Input1');
 var emp4put1Field = $('#emp4Input1');
 var emp5put1Field = $('#emp5Input1');

 // LISTEN FOR KEYPRESS EVENT
 emp5put1Field.keypress(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  //FIELD VALUES
  var date = date1Field.val();
  var emp1put1 = emp1put1Field.val();
  var emp2put1 = emp2put1Field.val();
  var emp3put1 = emp3put1Field.val();
  var emp4put1 = emp4put1Field.val();
  var emp5put1 = emp5put1Field.val();

  //SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD
  dateRef.push({date:date, emp1:emp1put1, emp2:emp2put1, emp3:emp3put1, emp4:emp4put1, emp5:emp5put1});
  emp5put1Field.val('');
   }
 });
```

});

This is what it is currently saving as

[image]

Id like it to output like:

```
     date:18/01
     --- emp1 = 9am
     --- emp2 = 10am
     --- emp3 = 11am
     --- emp4 = 12am
     --- emp5 = 2pm
```

Comment: I have tried dateRef = ref.child("#date1input"); but it doesnt allow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `update()`. `push()` creates a unique id as the parent of your data and then saves it under the tree you specified. Try this instead:

```
//SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD
var obj = {};
obj[date] = {
    emp1:emp1put1, 
    emp2:emp2put1, 
    emp3:emp3put1, 
    emp4:emp4put1, 
    emp5:emp5put1
}

dateRef.set(obj);
emp5put1Field.val('');
```

*`set()` will overwrite the data, while `update()` will only overwrite data of the same keys (if you tried to insert another object of the same date it would be overwritten, otherwise it will be "pushed" onto `roster/`)

Firebase has great documentation and pages dedicated to saving data:

[Saving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html)

Comment: thanks so much! Im trying to create a section function with the code you have provided and it works perfectly for the first one it gives an error for the second one?

Comment: im trying to enter dates in for the 19-01 and all the dates and that goes in fine, but then when i try to enter dates for the 20-01 and all the dates it deletes the 19th?

Comment: It shouldn't, study this https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html and its probably a small fix

Comment: ive looked at this and just got confused.